# Syntax for writing complex Json to the Cloud Firestore using Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, json, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have webhook that delivers a JSON payload to my Cloud Function URL. The Cloud Function will take the JSON, and write it to the Cloud Firestore.

I don't know how to handle this case where the complex JSON has brackets [].

My guess is there is some addition syntax I must add for cases like this, where the complex JSON has brackets.

Additionally, for the schema in my cloud firestore, I am trying to take the id from line_items and write it to a Map data type called "line_items" with a single field titled id_line_items.

**index.js**

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.webhook = async (req, res) => {
  const payload = req.body;

  await admin.firestore().collection("testCollection1").doc().set({
  
  line_items: {
    id_line_items: payload.line_items.id,
    },
  });
  return res.status(200).end();
}
```

**Json Payload**

```json
"line_items": [
        {
            "id": 97,
        }
    ],
```

**I experience no errors when the JSON payload looks like this:** Notice how this payload does not have the brackets []

```json
"billing": {
        "id": "97",
    },
```

Comment: Why billing? From where come this object?

Comment: The JSON payload that has `"billing":` is a payload that I have no trouble with. It is an example of a json payload that writes perfectly to the cloud firestore. I suspect, its because it does not have brackets []. The `"line_items":` payload has brackets [], and I believe, this might require additional syntax, which may be causing the error.

Comment: Do you have error traces?

Comment: Those square brackets denote an array (more than one object) so you cannot access the `id` of the line item if you don't specify which one. You might want to store all line items. I suggest you brush up on javascript objects and arrays and then how firestore documents and collections are similar to those.

Comment: Google Cloud Platform isn't giving me any errors in the Logs. So I need to learn how to identify an array in my json payload, and figure out how to write that array to the cloud firestore. thank you. So for my example, I probably need to specify `payload.line_items[0].id` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

The Json in question was an array, and I needed to specify the position.

```js
id_line_items: payload.line_items.id,
```

needs to be changed to:

```js
id_line_items: payload.line_items[0].id,
```